# "Range not found" error in sendEmails function and debugging isn't specific enough to identify

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, foreach, range

Would anyone be able to identify what is going on? It seems like a loop error of some type but I'm not sure myself.

The "Exception: Range not found" error message I am receiving references the lines:
`rows.forEach(function(row)`
and
`var eventEmail = eventsData.getRange(row[5]).getValue();`.

My columns are set up as:
Checkbox column
Title
StartDate
EndDate
Description
Email
Contact person

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR5XT.png)

```
function SendEmails ()
{
// Extract events data
  var eventsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME"); 
  var rows = eventsData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME_2").getRange(1, 1).getValue();

// Discount header row
  var headers = rows.shift();
 
// Identify only rows that are checked to apply function and run log
  rows.forEach(function(row) 
  {
    if(row[0])
    {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));

// Extract reminder template and send reminder emails for selection
      var eventEmail = eventsData.getRange(row[5]).getValue();
      var eventTitle = eventsData.getRange(row[1]).getValue();
      var eventPOC = eventsData.getRange(row[6]).getValue();
      var eventDesc = eventsData.getRange(rows[4]).getValue();
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",eventPOC).replace("{title}",eventTitle).replace("{description}",eventDesc);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder: " + eventTitle + " Upcoming Event";

      MailApp.sendEmail(eventEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
    }
  });
}
```

This function was working until I made some edits so that it only runs for rows that have checkboxes selected.

It seems to be successful in recognizing the rows that have checked checkboxes. It also seems to run through the first loop, but something happens after that which I haven't been able to identify.

I have tried to changes the range references to ensure the right columns are being references.

I appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Could you share the sample data, please?  For example, what is the output of `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));` immediately before the error?

Comment: This is the result from Logger: [true,"Event A","2024-01-28T13:00:00.000Z","2024-01-28T22:00:00.000Z","Event A job","email","POC",""]

I have 8 rows that are checked but just one is recorded in the Logger. I do have an extra column with a header that isn't populated with any data, but I don't think that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with this and similar lines: `eventsData.getRange(row[5]).getValue()`.  `getRange(row[5])` throws an error because the range with coordinates/name equal to the value of `row[5]` does not exist.

You have already extracted values from the spreadsheet, so you can directly use the `row` array like this: `var eventEmail = row[5]`.

This is the updated code:

```js
function SendEmails() {
  // Extract events data
  var eventsData =
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  var rows = eventsData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME_2")
    .getRange(1, 1)
    .getValue();

  // Discount header row
  var headers = rows.shift();

  // Identify only rows that are checked to apply function and run log
  rows.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[0]) {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));

      // Extract reminder template and send reminder emails for selection
      var eventEmail = row[5];
      var eventTitle = row[1];
      var eventPOC = row[6];
      var eventDesc = rows[4];
      var messageBody = templateText
        .replace("{name}", eventPOC)
        .replace("{title}", eventTitle)
        .replace("{description}", eventDesc);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder: " + eventTitle + " Upcoming Event";

      MailApp.sendEmail(eventEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I very much appreciate this, dataful! This is solved and your simple explanation makes sense in that once values are extracted, they don't need to be extracted again.